# shadow of link size is greater than size of button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using using link to open new tab in browser and button tag to look like button, this works fine however i face problem when i hover on button , shadow of link size is greater than size of button, i tried to set size of button bigger than size of link that dint work too, any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("CreatePDF", "CreateApplicationFromSearch", new { Applicant_id = Model.applicant_id, Application_id = Model.application_id, ShowPDF = true })" target="_blank"><input type="button" value="Print"
```